# Web uploader  issue using Uploadify

Tags: yui, uploadify, progress, uploader

I am working on a website that allows my clients to upload large amount of high resolution image files to my system. I have tried couple of uploaders but they don't seem to be as reliable as I was expecting - especially on Windows.

I have tried the following:

1. Uploadify 2 and 3
2. YUI Uploader (Yahoo Uploader)

The above uploaders all relies on Adobe Flash.

One of the most noticeable problem which is common to the mentioned uploaders is that the progress does not seem to work on Windows. It either stuck on 100% or 0% until the upload is actually finished. The files seems to be uploading fine but progress bar is totally out. This isn't a problem on a MAC though. I believe the problem is not within my code because even the uploaders' demo sites suffers the same problem.

On top of that I have heard clients complain about the uploaders being "self aborted" after say 33 files or so. They just don't seem to be that reliable.

My questions are:

1. Is there any way around this? To improve the visual at least (make the progress bar goes under windows)
2. Are there any other uploaders/methods that allows my clients to deliver large amount of files to my server reliably?

Running out of ideas and my clients are getting frustrated.